# How do rogues switch weapons?

Tags: weapons, rogue, heroes-and-treasure

We have started a game of [Heroes & Treasure](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/727578181/heroes-and-treasure-rpg-board-game?ref=card), a family-friendly tabletop RPG accessible to kids. Looking ahead, I notice that at level 5 rogues gain the ability to switch between weapons:

> Level 5: Can switch between any available weapons at will.

This ability is confusing to me, because throughout the rulebook (about 8 pages) there is no mention of equipment or different kinds of weapons. I can't speak to all of the published levels or adventures, but the 2 levels we are playing tonight also don't mention any specific equipment. There are also no tokens for different equipment.

So how does the rogue's ability to switch weapons work? Where do the weapons come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Additional weapons can be found as treasure

*(Full disclosure: I haven't played it myself, but I was researching for the tag excerpt — prevents them from being automatically deleted — and found pdf's of the core rules and the first adventure [on their website](https://heroesandtreasure.com).)*

In *The adventure of the mystic Rubies* there is a treasure chest in room:

> B on level 4

Which contains for the rogue:

> [image]

Answer (score -2):

I don't think I have my copy of Heroes & Treasure handy (pretty sure I loaned it to some friends with a six-or-seven year old), but from memory I think this ability means the Rogue can attack in melee or at range, where other classes are restricted to one or the other.  I'll go look for my copy, though, and see if I can cite some actual support to improve this answer.

Comment: In general, it is better to wait until you can access your copy to answer the question; unsupported speculation helps no one. You may want to delete your answer in the interim, lest you risk accumulating downvotes in the meantime.